# subethasmtp server not printing messages from client

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtpclient

When I run the client it's supposed to send an email to my server and then I want my email server to print out the email details (to, from, port, message) to console. For some reason after running the client, nothing apparent happens on the server.

**server**

```
package example;

import org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer;

public class EmailServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMessageHandlerFactory myFactory = new MyMessageHandlerFactory();
        SMTPServer smtpServer = new SMTPServer(myFactory);
        smtpServer.setPort(25000);
        smtpServer.start();
    }
}
```

**server output**

> run: [main] INFO org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer - SMTP server
>   *:25000 starting [org.subethamail.smtp.server.ServerThread *:25000] INFO org.subethamail.smtp.server.ServerThread - SMTP server *:25000
>   started

**client**

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.subethamail.smtp.client.*;

public class EmailClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SMTPClient sc = new SMTPClient();
            sc.close();
            sc.connect("localhost", 25000);
            sc.sendReceive("test");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

**client output**

> run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Version is **3.1.7** from https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/downloads/list

The server requires **MyMessageHandlerFactory** which I copied from: https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/wiki/SimpleExample

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's check the source code (always a good idea) and see what happens.

You send "test" via

```
SMTPClient sc;
sc.sendReceive("test"); // which is actually sent to your SMTPServer as "test\r\n"
```

Now, considering that this is a new SMTP conversation (see [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) for everything you always wanted to know but were afraid to ask about such things) and "**test**" isn't a valid command VERB at this point in the conversation, you would expect to see an error returned by `sendReceive()`.

But since you're ignoring the [SMTPClient.Response#75](https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/subethamail/smtp/client/SMTPClient.java#75) returned from what should have been

```
Response resp=SMTPClient.sendReceive()
```

you're missing out on both

- `resp.code` (which I am sure is `500 - Permanent Negative Completion reply / Syntax` - see the RFC above) and
- `resp.message` describing the reason your command could not be fulfulled

both of which are returned from [CommandHandler#93](https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/subethamail/smtp/server/CommandHandler.java#93).

Comment: Oh and regarding your `IOException` try/catch, the transaction doesn't fail. Rather it dutifully returns enough information for you to triage your problem, should you choose to attend to it. :-)

Comment: So, I'm brand new to this library and have never touched it before. In order to get my server to print out the email from the client could you tell me what basic code-level changes need to be made?

Comment: Just following up, have you had a chance to look into my previous comment by any chance?

Comment: @ThreaT - You'll need to call your sendReceive with the proper SMTP commands required to send a message, and at each step, capture the returned result from sc.sendReceive to assure your command has been accepted. For a typical SMTP conversation, you'll need to send, in order, 'HELO', 'MAIL FROM', 'RCPT TO', and 'DATA' commands. See http://www.earthinfo.org/example-smtp-conversation/ for more.

Comment: From what I can see `sendReceive(String msg)` only has this one method and does not get overloaded anywhere else. Could you give an example of how I would change the client to send the correct data over to the server in code format by any chance?

Comment: @ThreaT - Please read the document to which I linked you. Communication between a SMTP client and a (possibly) remote MTA is a text conversation, where your client connects to the MTA and says 'HELO example.com' to identify itself (replacing 'example.com' with the correct fully-qualified domain name of your client) to which the MTA will reply '250 ....' to indicate its willingness to continue the conversation. __ALL__ communication between client and server is conducted as plain text. Everything else you need is in the documentation I linked.